# What is the error bound in the classical error threshold theorem?

Tags: fault-tolerance

For unreliable classical computation there is [an error threshold theorem due to von Neumann analogous to the quantum error threshold theorem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/reference-request-classical-analog-of-quantum-threshold-theorem) that shows that even if gates produce the wrong result at some rate, as long as this rate is below a certain threshold the total error probability can be reduced arbitrarily by adding some polynomial overhead.

For the quantum threshold there is a lot of active research trying to pin down bounds, but are there any corresponding results for classical computation error thresholds?

The best bound I know of on the polynomial overhead is from ([Spielman 1996](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/548474)): a computation taking time $T$ on $N$ error-prone processors can be run using $N \log^{O(1)}(N)$ processors in time $T \log^{O(1)}(N)$ with failure probability at most $t \exp(-N^{1/4})$. But are there known values of the O(1) constants? And there is no explicit estimate of the threshold error rate.